# Custom Font Cut Off

Tags: andengine

I have problem facing related to custom font.
Following image illustrate better what I am trying to say.

[image]

Following is the code snippet that I used at present.

```
    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {
            BitmapTextureAtlas mComixLoudFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(256,
                            256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
            mComixLoudFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(mComixLoudFontTexture,
                            this, "Comix_Loud.ttf", 40, true, Color.BLACK);

            BitmapTextureAtlas mLCDFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(256, 256,
                            TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
            mLCDFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(mLCDFontTexture, this,
                            "LCD.ttf", 40, true, Color.BLACK);

            this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(mComixLoudFontTexture,
                            mLCDFontTexture);
            this.mEngine.getFontManager().loadFonts(mComixLoudFont, mLCDFont);
    }

    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
            mScene = new Scene();
            mScene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));
            mScene.attachChild(new Text(230, 100, mComixLoudFont, "Comix Loud Font"));
            mScene.attachChild(new Text(230, 200, mLCDFont, "LCD Font"));
            return mScene;
    }
```

In some font type it create problem and in some it work perfect. So what to do in situation like this? I already set large texture atlas size but it didn't work for me.

Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two approaches available to fix this issue.

1) You can manually create you bitmap font texture using a utility like [Bitmap Font Generator](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) or [Glyf Designer](http://www.71squared.com/en/glyphdesigner) and then load it using the [BitmapFont](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/opengl/font/BitmapFont.java) class. This is the best option, I think.

2) You need to increase the padding variable on your text bitmap so it doesn't cut off the top.  I'm not sure this will work. But in theory it would extend the area around all the letters and make the letters spaced out in each word. Not the best option.

Comment: Thanks, I will check these both thing and reply you which one work for me.

Comment: I apply your second suggestion and post move detail in following post. http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/custom-font-cut-off-t12562.html